# Is it possible to register to a conference after the deadline

Tags: conference, deadlines

I was accepted as a participant for this conference but unfortunately, I completely forgot to register and pay the fee.

The deadline was May 30, and the conference starts on Jul 25.

What should I write in an email to apologize and ask if it's possible a late registration?

(I'm not a speaker, but I'd have presented a poster)

Comment: By "accepted as participant", do you mean that your poster was accepted? Or something else?

Comment: No, I mean just my participation (I haven't made the request for the poster yet)

Comment: This looks unusual to me. How did you get accepted? Usually, at least in my field, the way one applies for participation is by registering and paying the fee. There is no separate, parallel system for accepting participants.

Comment: For acceptance, we send a motivation letter explaining our background and expertise and then, if accepted, we proceed with registration (this step basically is just the payment of the conference fee).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the apology short and to the point. Keep the request short and to the point.

Comment: It worked, they have registered me